# Is cp faster between the same filesystem than different ones?

Tags: filesystems, performance

Have been thinking heavily on what the idea of -x of cp option led to suspect that the copying is faster between two same fs than 2 different ones.
And using `cp --reflink=auto` or using `cp --u`
which one faster, more efficient
Please explain, prove it true or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ObPOSIX: none of the `cp` options discussed here are standard.

`cp -x` isn’t about copying within the same file system; it causes [recursive descents to only consider directories and files in the same file system](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html). This allows users to run, for example,

```
cp -rx / /somewhereelse
```

to back up the root file system without copying any other file system (including `/proc` etc.). `/somewhereelse` can be on another file system (and should be, in this case).

The `-x` option applies per argument, so `cp -rx / /home /somewhereelse` will copy whatever is visible under `/`, and separately under `/home`, without crossing file system boundaries; it will work even if `/` and `/home` are not on the same file system.

As far as performance goes, any option which reduces the amount of data to copy will increase the speed of the overall operation. Thus `cp -u`, when copying to a directory which already has copies of (some) of the source files, will be faster because it won’t copy any file which has the same timestamp or newer than the corresponding source file. `cp --reflink=auto` will be faster still wherever it can use a reflink, because that avoids copying data blocks entirely.